# Backpropagating a Dueling Architecture Network: Gradient Calculation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation

I started coding a [Dueling Network Architectures for Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06581v3.pdf).
I devided my network into two streams, arriving at a V(s) value and A(s,a) values.
I arrived at the Q(s,a) output values by calculating: 
Q(s,a) = V(s) + ( A(s,a) - Mean of All A(s,a) )

Now my problem is with backpropagation. After calculating the loss, how do I calculate the gradients of V(s) and A(s,a) without there being any weights?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Both V and A are networks and therefore have weights.

Comment: but when we get to V and A, how do we get to Q? through weights? or through the calculation above?

Comment: through the calculation above. There's no part of backpropagation that requires that all layers have weights though. Pooling layers don't, for example.

Comment: @DaVinci Ah sorry I wasn't aware of that. So how do you train the network then? What I know to do is use the gradient to adjust weights. (beginner, obviously)

Comment: Just implement backprop and you get the gradient for the weights of both V and A. Or, if you implement it in a library such as theano or tensorflow, simply do the Q(s, a) = V(s) + (A(s,a) - mean_a A(s,a)) in theano or tensorflow operations and it will get the gradients for you. You'd have a V tensor and an A tensor and you can define a Q tensor via, Q = V + A + T.mean(V, axis=1).

Comment: @DaVinci Thanks a lot, I'm looking into it. Only problem is that I'm coding this network in MQL4, so I cannot implement these. I have to code them and do the calculations myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient in DQN is given by

[image]

Since Q is a simple sum of functions you have:

$$\nabla_{\theta} Q(s,a) = \nabla_{\theta}V(s) + \nabla{\theta}A(s,a) - \frac{1}{numActions} \sum_{a'}\nabla_{\theta}A(s, a')$$

You get the gradients of the V and A networks as usual by backprop.

Comment: Could we say that Delta(v) = V(s) * ( 1 - V(s) ) *  Sum of Deltas Q(s,a) ?
If so, what about Deltas of A(s,a)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But you don't need to calculate the deltas separately since you can simply calculate the Q values given V and A.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my problem is with backpropagation. After calculating the loss, how do I calculate the gradients of V(s) and A(s,a) without there being any weights?
>
> If so, what about Deltas of A(s,a)

Looking at the comments from the currently accepted answer, I'd like to add mine too.

[This post from Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54050/43077) shows the gradient vector that should enter V and A layers respectively.